# Can CSS3 Flex take only integer values?

Tags: css, flexbox

I often use CSS3 flexboxes - they make for easy, flexible layouts.  CSS along the lines of

```
-webkit-box-flex: 4;
-moz-box-flex: 4;
-ms-flex: 4;
-webkit-flex: 4;
flex: 4;
```

is never a problem.  However, I now have a situation where I need to provide a floating point value.  I mean something along the lines of

```
-webkit-box-flex: 4.1;
-moz-box-flex: 4.1;
-ms-flex: 4.1;
-webkit-flex: 4.1;
flex: 4.1;
```

A quick and dirty experiment test - hot edits to the CSS in the console followed by width measurements in Chrome and Firefox with the PicPick pixel ruler - suggests that this works. However, I have not been able to find any definitive information  - I tried the W3C docs but found them a bit to dense.  The ever reliable [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) does not quite clarify this either - on the subject.  Could someone here tell me whether such fractional values are safe to use with the majority of recent mainstream browsers today?

Comment: The flex property actually takes multiple values: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex Might I ask why you'd expect to find this information on a site like caniuse?

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks.  I see you deleted your answer.  I accepted kRIST's answer in the meantime since he gives examples of what is meant by *valid numbers*

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my answer as it had been made redundant in favor of his.

Comment: @BoltClock - you are right.  It isn't too reasonable to expect this kind of detail on caniuse.  I mentioned it in passing just to indicate where I had been looking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Mozilla Docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex , it takes a [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number) value - which includes non-integers according to the MDN docs. All valid number values:

```
12          A raw <integer> is also a <number>
4.01        A positive non-integer <number>
-456.8      Negative non-integer <number>
0.0         Zero
+0.0        Zero, with a leading +
-0.0        Zero, with a leading - (Though strange, this is an allowed value)
.60         Digits are optional before the dot
10e3        The scientific notation is allowed
-3.4e-2     Most complex case of scientific notatio
```